# How can I measure cache misses on an iphone via an API?

Tags: ios, iphone, caching, profiling

I would like to measure L2 cache misses in an iphone application. 
I am looking for an API/code, that is similar to the mach task info APIs that provide things like CPU usage.

Comment: Tested further, Instruments is also no able to record cache misses on a device. The "counters" instrument works fine for runs on the simulator, but reports performance counters are not supported for runs on a device.